# yalantis tabbar for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

Im having trouble using Yalantis Folding Tabbar for iOS:
https://github.com/Yalantis/FoldingTabBar.iOS

I've done what they told on their github page which means:

- Setting the classes in Storyboard to the Yalantis custom classes
- Added Swift Code Snippet to AppDelegate class
- Changed the options from section: Important notes of their Github page
- Added icons from the example project to my project

My tabbar is however blank (white with nothing in it)

Does anyone have a hint what Im missing here?
Thank you

Comment: I would recommend going back through their example project to understand all the parts that are needed for it to work, and see what's not in yours. Additionally, you need to be more descriptive and provide code snippets to help us to see what you've done. If you think it's something wrong with the Tab Bar, try posting an issue in the github repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines of code to your appDelegate part of TabBar

```
tabBarController.tabBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                                                  red: 94.0/255.0,
                                                  green: 91.0/255.0,
                                                  blue: 149.0/255.0,
                                                  alpha: 1
                                              )

tabBarController.tabBarView.tabBarColor = UIColor(
                                              red: 72.0/255.0,
                                              green: 211.0/255.0,
                                              blue: 178.0/255.0,
                                              alpha: 1
                                          )

tabBarController.tabBarView.dotColor = UIColor(
                                           red: 94.0/255.0,
                                           green: 91.0/255.0,
                                           blue: 149.0/255.0,
                                           alpha: 1
                                       )
```

seems that you have white background and white buttons are blending in a color